# How do I send data table content from one component to another component?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, datatable

I got one component, where I fill the data table with information. The material card looks like this:

[image]

I want to put exactly the same information in another component. Everything works, except with the data table. And I'm not quite sure, how to solve that problem. Following how it looks at the moment:

[image]

Following some code:

TS for the component, where the information should go. I need to use dataSource I think, since I'm using it for the other component. I'm using @Input to get the block, which was sent from the other component. But how do I put all the transactions into the ELEMENT_DATA, so that it gets displayed in the table?

```
export class BlockCardComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['sender', 'recipient', 'amount', 'fee'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Transaction>(ELEMENT_DATA);


  @Input() block: Block;
}
```

Bits of HTML of that component: At the moment I'm just doing it like that.

```
 <mat-card-content>
    <p>{{block.transactions | json}}</p>
  </mat-card-content>
```

TS of the component, where the information comes from:

```
export class MinerViewComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  transaction: Transaction;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['sender', 'recipient', 'amount', 'fee'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Transaction>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  temp: Transaction[] = [];
  blockNumber = 1;
  previousHash = '00000000000000000000000000000000';
  blockHash: string = this.generateFirstHash();
  blockHashList: string[] = [];

  message: any;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private _TS: TransactionPoolToMinerService, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
              private toolbarToMVService: ToolbarToMVService, private _MS: MinerViewToBlockchainService) {
    this.subscription = this.toolbarToMVService.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
      this.message = message;
      this.sendBlockToBC();
      this.clearBlock();
    });
  }
sendBlockToBC() {
    const block = new Block(this.blockNumber, this.temp, this.previousHash, this.blockHash);
    this._MS.emitTransaction(block);
    console.log(block);
    this.dataSource = undefined; // to empty the table in the miner view component
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Transaction>(ELEMENT_DATA); // create new datasource to fill the table,
    // since the old one gives an error
    this.generateBlockHash();
    this.raiseBlockNumber();
  }
}
```

HTML of that component for the data table:

```
 <mat-card-content>

    <div>
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="sender">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Sender </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.sender}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="recipient">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Empfänger </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.recipient}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Betrag </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.amount}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="fee">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Gebühr </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.fee}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </mat-card-content>
```

Comment: You can use `Input` decorator, or using a service with `Subject`. Or, if nested/ inside another component you can use `ViewChild` decorator.

Comment: I would recommend that you put the code that gets the data into a service. You can then inject the service the same way you inject `RouterModule` for example. Once it is injected, you can access all data from the service in either module.